# Enqueue custom jQuery UI theme to override Google CDN theme

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, jquery-ui

I'm trying to override the jQuery UI theme that wordpress enqueued from Google CDN link but I have not found a solution to my issue. I have my stylesheet enqueued correctly in my plugin but the styles are being overridden. It shows the custom css file being loaded before the CDN and have been trying to find a solution. I tried changing the priority to 999 but no luck.

I looked in my parent theme functions.php and includes to look where it was being enqueued but didn't find anything. This is completely frustrating that WordPress doesn't have a tool to change the theme or easily upload one.

Can I deregister/dequeue the style using a handle? Any help is appreciated.

Please don't give me links to the Codex about how to use wp_enqueue_scripts.

Comment: WordPress has tools to upload and change your theme in the admin section under Appearance > Themes.  Neither Jquery UI or any of its themes are loaded by default with WordPress, so some plugin or theme you have installed is.  Yes, you can deregister/dequeue styles, but you need to know the handle, look at the `$wp_style` and `$wp_scripts` globals.

Comment: Also, WordPress debugging 101, this will save you a lot of hassle in the future.  Make sure you're on a development/local environment so you're not messing with a live site.  Deactivate *all* plugins and switch to a default theme.  Make sure whatever problem you were having is solved.  Then, reactivate the plugins and theme one by one to figure out which one is causing the issue.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849684/wordpress-jquery-ui-css-files